# How can I fix "ImportError: no module named shell" error for IPython

Tags: python, ipython

I've seen a number of people recommend that I use the following snippet to embed an IPython shell or drop to an IPython shell from e.g. a django view.

```
from IPython.Shell import IPShellEmbed
ipython = IPShellEmbed()
ipython()
```

But when I do this, I get

```
>>> from IPython.Shell import IPShellEmbed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named Shell
```

How can I embed IPython or start an IPython console from an existing python app?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The solution is to [use the following](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/reference.html#embedding-ipython) instead:

```
import IPython
IPython.embed()
```

[Issue 286](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/286) on the [IPython github repo](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/) explains that the Shell module has moved and should [no longer be used](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/286#issuecomment-835523).

Comment: You can add an alias in shell config file with `alias 'ipython'='python -m IPython'`