# Is it possible to use bpython as a full debugger?

Tags: python, debugging, bpython

I would like to use the [bpython](http://bpython-interpreter.org/) interpreter for debugging. 
My question is similar to "[Is it possible to go into ipython from code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126930/is-it-possible-to-go-into-ipython-from-code)", which asks about ipython.

If you use `ipdb.set_trace()` you get a full [ipython](http://ipython.org/) session with all of its conveniences. However, `bpdb.set_trace()` doesn't give me a bpython session, it gives me the standard `pdb` debugger.

Is there any way of setting things up so that I can debug within a bpython session?

Comment: Would it cost you a lot to try it?

Comment: @Marcin I should clarify that `bpdb.set_trace()` gives me the standard `pdb` debugger

Comment: So, is that a problem? How does a question arise from that?

Comment: Yes: If you use `ipdb.set_trace()` you get a full `ipython` debugger session with all of its conveniences. In my opinion `bpython` is much nicer to work with, however `bpdb.set_trace()` doesn't give me a `bpython` session

Comment: @MRE Yep, it's doable. See my answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Yes,** using [this wrapper](https://hg.bpython-interpreter.org/bpython/src/5c1f2b5cf054/bpdb/debugger.py), which you can also access by adding the statement `import bpdb` to your code. Add `bpdb.set_trace()` wherever you want to break, and from the `pdb` interpreter enter "B" to jump into a `bpython` session with everything from the stack frame:

```
# The MIT License
#
# Copyright (c) 2008 Bob Farrell
#
# Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
# of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
# in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
# to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
# copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
# furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
#
# The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
# all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
#
# THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
# IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
# FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
# AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
# LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
# OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
# THE SOFTWARE.


import pdb
import bpython

class BPdb(pdb.Pdb):
    """ PDB with BPython support. """

    def __init__(self):
        pdb.Pdb.__init__(self)
        self.rcLines = []
        self.prompt = '(BPdb) '
        self.intro = 'Use "B" to enter bpython, Ctrl-d to exit it.'

    def postloop(self):
        # We only want to show the intro message once.
        self.intro = None
        pdb.Pdb.postloop(self)

    ### cmd.Cmd commands


    def do_Bpython(self, arg):
        bpython.embed(self.curframe.f_locals, ['-i'])


    def help_Bpython(self):
        print "B(python)"
        print
        print ("Invoke the bpython interpreter for this stack frame. To exit "
               "bpython and return to a standard pdb press Ctrl-d")


    ### shortcuts
    do_B = do_Bpython
    help_B = help_Bpython
```

Your question seems perfectly valid to me!

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing me to this, but this is just a wrapper around `pdb`. It's included in the `bpdb` module. When I use it, it just gives me the `pdb` debugger (i.e. no highlighting, completion, docs, etc). Unless it does something different on your machine?

Comment: @MrE This seems to be the extent provided for `bpython`, but Amjith is absolutely right. For extending `pdb` to be pleasant as a debugger, `pdb++` is the way to go. :)

Comment: on further inspection, aka reading the code above, from the `pdb` debugger session if you type "B" you jump into a `bpython` session. So I've marked this as correct.

Comment: @MrE I'm glad both of us here were able to assist you! I do apologize on behalf of my peers for the initial downvotes and terse responses you received. I'm just glad we were able to step in and help. :)

Comment: No need to apologise. Hope you don't mind if I added the rest of the info to your answer. Feel free to reword if you like.

Comment: @MrE No worries at all. Thanks for taking the time to explain your problem and help us help you (help us all).

Answer (score 12):

If you are looking for a cooler looking debugger that does completion and syntax highlighting you might want to take a look at pdb++. http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdbpp/

[image]

It's a drop in replacement for pdb. So you can continue to use

```
 import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

and it'll drop you into the pdb++ prompt.

Comment: Hey, this is really nice. Not quite as slick as bpython (in interactive mode) but still a big and painless upgrade.

Comment: I agree, the completion isn't quite as awesome as bpython. I like the sticky feature, where the code is shown above and highlights the current line that is being executed.

Comment: Having pdbpp already installed with python3.7+, you can just call `breakpoint` builtin and pdbpp debugger will take place