# using ipdb to debug python code in one cell (jupyter or Ipython)

Tags: debugging, cell, jupyter, ipdb

I'm using jupyter (or Ipython) notebook with firefox, and want to debug some python code in the cell. I am using 'import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()' as kind of breakpoint, for example my cell has the following code:

```
a=4
import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
b=5
print a
print b
```

which after execution with Shift+Enter gives me this error:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
MultipleInstanceError                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-f2b356251c56> in <module>()
      1 a=4
----> 2 import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
      3 b=5
      4 print a
      5 print b

/home/nnn/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipdb/__init__.py in <module>()
     14 # You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License along with this program. If not, see http://www.gnu.org/licenses/.
     15 
---> 16 from ipdb.__main__ import set_trace, post_mortem, pm, run, runcall, runeval, launch_ipdb_on_exception
     17 
     18 pm                       # please pyflakes

/home/nnn/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipdb/__main__.py in <module>()
     71         # the instance method will create a new one without loading the config.
     72         # i.e: if we are in an embed instance we do not want to load the config.
---> 73         ipapp = TerminalIPythonApp.instance()
     74         shell = get_ipython()
     75         def_colors = shell.colors

/home/nnn/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/configurable.pyc in instance(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    413             raise MultipleInstanceError(
    414                 'Multiple incompatible subclass instances of '
--> 415                 '%s are being created.' % cls.__name__
    416             )
    417 

MultipleInstanceError: Multiple incompatible subclass instances of TerminalIPythonApp are being created.
```

The same error appears if I use this code not in the jupyter notebook in the browser, but in jupyter qtconsole. 
What does this error mean and what to do to avoid it? 
Is it possible to debug code in the cell step-by-step, using next, continue, etc commands of pdb debugger?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Had this problem also and it seems to be related to versions of jupyter and ipdb.

Solution is to use this instead of the ipdb library `set_trace` call:

```py
from IPython.core.debugger import Tracer
Tracer()() #this one triggers the debugger
```

Source: http://devmartin.com/blog/2014/10/trigger-ipdb-within-ipython-notebook/

Annotated screenshot:
[image: screenshot illustrate how Tracer()() will cause Jupyter notebook to react. It pauses execution on the line in your code where you Trace()() and a new "inline" input accepts ipdb commands like 'p' or 'n' or 'c', shown here]

Comment: Thanks Robert, this solution seems to work. I can get into  ipdb prompt,  check and print my variables. However any attempt to continue (c) or execute next statement (n) just kills the kernel! Every time I try to do it I just see "Dead Kernel" in my browser, or _sys.excepthook = old_excepthook_ with SystemExit exception in qtconsole. Did you have the same problems?

Comment: @lugger1 no, I didn't have that problem. It worked fine for me. I'm afraid I've no idea what would cause that. Upgrade versions?

Comment: This worked fine for me and doesn't kill the kernel. Thanks Robert!

Comment: How can you quit the debugging. `exit` and `ctrl-d` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Ctrl-D doesn't work, but both `exit` and `quit` did for me

Comment: That `devmartin` blog post quoted here references [a different SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14635299/1175496)

Comment: Use `q` to quit the debugger, and use `h` to see a list of debugging commands.

Comment: `Tracer()` is deprecated. Use `from IPython.core.debugger import set_trace` and then place `set_trace()` where breakpoint is needed.

Answer (score 21):

`Tracer()` is deprecated.

Use:

`from IPython.core.debugger import set_trace`

and then place `set_trace()` where breakpoint is needed.

```
from IPython.core.debugger import set_trace

def add_to_life_universe_everything(x):
    answer = 42
    set_trace()
    answer += x

    return answer

add_to_life_universe_everything(12)
```

This works fine and brings us a little bit more comfort (e.g. syntax highlighting) than just using the built-in pdb.

[source](https://davidhamann.de/2017/04/22/debugging-jupyter-notebooks/#tldr)

Answer (score 14):

If using Jupyter Notebook 
begin your cell with magic command "**%%debug**".
Then a ipdb line will be shown at the bottom of the cell which will help you navigate through the debugging session. Following commands should get you started:

**n**- execute current line and go to next line.

**c**- continue execution until next break point.

Make sure you restart the kernel each time you decide on debugging, so that all variables are freshly assigned.You can check the value of each variable through the ipdb line and you will see that the variable is undefined until you execute the line that assigns a value to that variable.

```
%%debug
import pdb
from pdb import set_trace as bp
def function_xyz():
    print('before breakpoint')
    bp() # This is a breakpoint.
    print('after breakpoint')
```

Comment: I have added a code which explains how we can add breakpoints in Jupyter notebook.

Comment: `import set_trace as bp` , that's funny, `set_trace()` does feel like the equivalent of setting a breakpoint :)

Answer (score 9):

My version of Jupyter is 5.0.0 and my corresponding ipython version is 6.1.0. I am using

```
import IPython.core.debugger
dbg = IPython.core.debugger.Pdb()
dbg.set_trace()
```

`Tracer` is listed as deprecated.

Update:

I tried using the method from another answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43086430/8019692 below but got an error:

`MultipleInstanceError: Multiple incompatible subclass instances of TerminalIPythonApp are being created.`

I prefer my method to the **%%debug** magic since I can set breakpoints in functions defined in other cells and run the function in another cell. Jupyter/IPython drops into the debugger in my function where the breakpoint is set, and I can use the usual `pdb` commands. To each his own...

@lugger1, the accepted answer is deprecated.

Comment: This one-liner works for me:  `from IPython.core.debugger import Pdb; Pdb().set_trace()`

Comment: For me on Windows 10, this does not lead to an interactive pdb prompt. The cell is just seeming to "run" and not responsive. I have to stop the execution.