# Interactive debugging in IPython (Jupyter) notebook

Tags: python, debugging, ipython, jupyter-notebook, ipdb

For debugging my python code, I use the `ipdb` library, and use the `set_trace()` command to place a break point. Once the code reaches there, I get an interactive shell with `ipdb>` prompt, that I can explore local variables with tab autocompletion.

In IPython (Jupyter) notebook, however, `ipdb.set_trace()` does not work. As suggested by this post:
[using ipdb to debug python code in one cell (jupyter or Ipython)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35613249/using-ipdb-to-debug-python-code-in-one-cell-jupyter-or-ipython)

I use the following alternative for interactive debugging:

```
from IPython.core.debugger import Tracer
Tracer()() #this one triggers the debugger
```

This gives me the `ipdb>` prompt, but the tab autocomplete is not available. Is there anyway to enable auto-complete for interactive debugging using ipython notebook? This is extremely useful, specially when you have a lot of variables with long names.

Comment: No, unfortunately the way those input prompts work does not allow tab completion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3.7 you can use [breakpoint()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#breakpoint) function

> This function drops you into the debugger at the call site.
>   Specifically, it calls sys.breakpointhook(), passing args and kws
>   straight through. By default, sys.breakpointhook() calls
>   pdb.set_trace() expecting no arguments. In this case, it is purely a
>   convenience function so you don’t have to explicitly import pdb or
>   type as much code to enter the debugger. However, sys.breakpointhook()
>   can be set to some other function and breakpoint() will automatically
>   call that, allowing you to drop into the debugger of choice.