# Debug Python Script Using Multiple Breakpoints in IPython

Tags: python, debugging, ipython, breakpoints

How do we set multiple breakpoints in Python using `IPython`, so that for example we stop at line 4 and line 100?

Also, can we change our mind and set extra breakpoints while already in debugging?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Breakpoint-induced interactive debugging of Python with IPython](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14635299/breakpoint-induced-interactive-debugging-of-python-with-ipython)

Comment: The question you mentioned seems to allow either only 1 breakpoint, either stepping line by line. I am interested in stopping at multiple locations, skipping the rest in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[iPython](https://ipython.org/) provides [IPython.core.debugger.Tracer](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/api/generated/IPython.core.debugger.html#IPython.core.debugger.Tracer) debugger class which can be used to debugging.

Let's say I have below code written in `myScript.py`:

```
from IPython.core.debugger import Tracer
zz = Tracer()

print "iPython"
zz()
print "is a"
print "command shell"
zz()
print "for"
print "interactive computing"
print "in"
print "multiple programming languages"
print "including"
print "Python"
```

As you can see I have set 2 breakpoints in the script from the beginning at Line 5 and 8. Below, I am running this script and will be setting 2 more breakpoints at line 12 & 13.

```
$ ipython myScript.py
iPython
> /home/user/Documents/myScript.py(6)<module>()
      4 print "iPython"
      5 zz()
----> 6 print "is a"
      7 print "command shell"
      8 zz()

ipdb> break 12
Breakpoint 1 at /home/user/Documents/myScript.py:12
ipdb> break 13
Breakpoint 2 at /home/user/Documents/myScript.py:13
```

Also, when inside debugging, you can use commands `c` for continue and `n` for next step. Hopefully, it helps you.

Comment: Thanks. What seems strange for me is why such a common language misses something such fundamental of a debugger and noone seems to bat an eye from what I googled.